# Split text by multiple capital letters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to split these text, knowing that a word has a minimum of two letters.

```
SAMAndMAX // SAM And MAX
SAMAndMax // SAM And Max
SamAndMax // Sam And Max
SamAndMAX // Sam And MAX
```

I've tried doing it this way `(?=[A-Z][a-z])`, but as you can't see it doesn't work properly.

```js
console.log('SAMAndMAX'.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/).join(' '))
console.log('SAMAndMax'.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/).join(' '))
console.log('SamAndMax'.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/).join(' '))
console.log('SamAndMAX'.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/).join(' '))
```

I can't seem to figure it out... Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SamAndMAX // SAM And Max`?

Comment: There is still a typo there, I believe it should be `SamAndMAX // Sam And MAX`.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi woops :)

Comment: So each word is either all caps or "title-case"? Can words have a single letter? If so, why `SAM` and not `S`, `A`, `M`?

Comment: @tobias_k words can't have a single letter in this case, always 2 or more

Comment: The main problem that you have to clarify for us here is: what is the logic for defining what a word is, it's clearly not just capital letters, otherwise the first example would decompose into `S`, `A`, `M`, `And`, `M`, `A`, and `X`.

Comment: With a lookbehind, perhaps `(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` https://regex101.com/r/SpNHAk/1

Comment: `SAMAndMax // SAM And Max` - what's the logic behind this?

Comment: @vaditaslim all capital letters, till a capital letter having after it a small letter. Knowing that if there's X capital letters, then the next word have a capital + small letter after it

Comment: Unless you have some sort of dictionary of acceptable words, this cannot be done as described. For example, what would the following string split into? `QWErtYuiop`

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi `QW Ert Yuiop`

Comment: Does it have to `split` or could it also match those as different groups?

Comment: @tobias_k it does need to split, as I'm using the result elsewhere afterwards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option for the example data is to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` with a positive lookbehind to assert a char a-z and a positive lookahead to assert a char A-Z

See this link https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind for the availability of lookbehinds.

```
(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

```js
console.log('SAMAndMAX'.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/).join(' '));
console.log('SAMAndMax'.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/).join(' '));
console.log('SamAndMax'.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/).join(' '));
console.log('SamAndMAX'.split(/(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/).join(' '));
```

Comment: Why not just replace the zero-width matches with a space?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think that will also introduce a leading space, see https://regex101.com/r/b4ZvQL/1

Comment: Ah, yes. That could be addressed with a small fix but that would complicate the regex: `(?=(?<!^)[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the use of lookbehinds one could match the following regular expression and then join the pieces with a space.

```
^[A-Z](?:[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][A-Za-z])|[a-z]+)|[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z])|[A-Z](?:[A-Z]+|[a-z]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PrE1ln/1)